# Let $A$ be the set of all rational $p$ such that $2 < p^2 < 3$.Then $A$ is choose the correct option

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let  $A$ be the set of all rational $p$ such that $2 < p^2 < 3$.Then $A$ is

choose the correct option

$1)$ compact in $\mathbb{Q}$

$2)$closed and bounded in $\mathbb{Q}$

$3)$Not  compact in $\mathbb{Q}$

$4)$ closed and unbounded in $\mathbb{Q}$

i thinks option $1)$ and $2)$ option will be correct by Heine Boral theorem

Is its True ?

Comment: It is not. You must think more carefully about compactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $A$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$. For instance, $\sqrt2$ belongs to $\overline A$, but not to $A$. So, $A$ is not compact and 1) doesn't hold. Besides, $A$ is clearly bounded and also closed in $\mathbb Q$, so 2) holds and 4) also hold. The correct choices are 2) and 3). If you want to show directly that $A$ is not compact (in $\mathbb Q$ or in $\mathbb R$, it doesn't matter), use the fact that it is not a closed set.

Comment: It is closed in $\mathbb Q$ because its complement is open.

Comment: But it is not a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ and therefore it is not compact.

Comment: Right, 2 and 3 are correct.

Comment: @JohnDouma I agree. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos one more  doubt  Can A be open in   $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The set $A$ *is* open on $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos..thanks u

Comment: `s/also/doesn't/` (typo). Be careful: $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$: can you point to a rational which is an accumulation point and doesn't belong to $A$?